# Determine if an array of numbers match a list of requirements

Tags: algorithm

Say you have an array of different numbers {5,6,1,67,13,9,14,15}, and a list of requirements like this: 
R1:you must select at least 2 numbers from set(5,6,10) which are also in your array in this case it will be 5,6

R2:you must select at least 3 numbers from set(9,13,67,5) which are also in your array. in this case it will be 9,13,67. Notice that we cannot select 5 since it has been used in R1

R3:you must select at least 2 numbers from set(1,14,15,6) which are also in your array. in this case it can be 1,14 or 1,15 or 14,15 we will have multiple satisfactions.
.....

.....

Rk:you must selet at least k numbers from set (.......) which are also in your array.

So the problem is to find a polynomial-time algorithm to determine if the given array matches all the requirement, and each number of the array can be only used to satisfy one requirement only.

my solution goes like this:

```
determine(array a,R[]) //R[] is a array of requirements, array a is our checking array
{
     if R is empty return true   //we satisfied all the requirments
     if R[0] cannot be satisfied by our array a return false
     for each satisfactions
     {
       new array b=a-selected numbers for this satisfaction
       new rule array newR=R-R[0]    //remove the first rule of the rule array
       if determine(b,newR) is false     //we begin our recursive call
           we continue our loop since this means the current way of satisfaction does not work
       else return true
      }
         return false   //this means we finish checking all the satisfactions and cannot find a match we need to tell the last recursive call that this way does not work    
}
```

Clearly my solution needs exponential time, anyone can come up with a polynomial solution?

Comment: Exponential time according to which parameter? (N, the size of set you want to check, or R*M, the number R of requirements of size M that have to be satisfied)? I think your solution may be factorial in R and polynomial in N.

Comment: It should actually be N*((R*M)*(R*M+1)+QR!) where Q depends on the (average) characteristics of the reduced requirement, e.g. if a requirement states K out of M numbers, Q = (M)!/(K!(M-K)!) , which does not depend on N.

Comment: Say first requirement have c1 satisfactions,think it as c1 path to requirement 2,second have c2 satisfactions,so c2 path to requirement 3  and so on, in worst case,my algorithm will need to check every path, which is c1*c2*c3.....*c(r), so the total cost will be some base c(average of c1,c2,c3...) with power r(number of requirements) c^r

Comment: At each step you generate c(i) combinations (on average Q) out of requirement r(i). Generating the "new" {N'} from a combination of size K costs O(KN), so one call costs O(QKN). You need c(1)*c(2)*...*c(r) calls, on average Q*R calls (not, as I had wrongly calculated, Q*R!). Total cost ought to be O(Q^2*K*N*R).

Comment: “You need c(1)*c(2)*...*c(r) calls, on average Q*R calls”

Comment: “You need c(1)*c(2)*...*c(r) calls, on average Q*R calls” It should be Q^R calls, if it's c(1)+c(2)+c(3)...+c(r) then it is Q*R calls, am i right?

Comment: Christ, I need to go to sleep :-(. Of course you're right.

Comment: so any thoughts for a polynomial solution?

Comment: Sorry, no. You could check all elements shared by multiple requirements (e.g. number 5 is in requirements 2, 7 and 9, number 6 is in requirements 8 and 11...) but worst case would still be exponential on the number of shared elements.

Answer (score 1):

After you satisfy all your requirements, you will have chosen each element in your array (c(0), c(1), c(2), ... , c(n)) times.

Where c(i) is 0 or 1. Your constraints tell you that c(i) + c(j) + c(k) = 2, for example.

I may be wrong but this seems like 0-1 integer programming, which is one of Karp's NP-complete problems, no?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_linear_programming#Integer_unknowns

Comment: how do you determine the constraint that c(i)+c(j)+c(k)=2? And I think there must be a polynomial solution for this problem

Comment: If you must choose two numbers from (i,j,k) it means that your constraint is c(i)+c(j)+c(k) = 2.